# Making linearlayouts scrollable in android

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout, scrollable

I am making an android application that needs to use a scrollable layout that contains a couple of linearlayouts, a textview and a listview. How can i make this happen??? Please help and thanks SO much in advance! This is the xml code that i am using so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical" >




<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NotesWelcomeTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/NotesWelcomeText" />








<ListView
    android:id="@+android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</ListView>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DeleteAllItemsFromListViewLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CancelButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Cancel" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DeleteAllButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Delete" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DeleteItemFromListViewLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:visibility="invisible" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Cancel" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/DeleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Delete" />

</LinearLayout>




<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/AddItemToListViewLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/AddItemToListViewEditText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </EditText>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddItemToListViewButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/Add" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You really don't want to put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView` unless the `ListView` only has a small number of items and isn't going to have to scroll as well. Scrolling views inside other scrolling views will cause you problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true">   
<TextView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="false"
     android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: this is example ok scroll view

Comment: didn't work, because a scrollview could only host a direct child

Answer (score 0):

Make your main layout as scroll layout inside that put the linear layout.

Keep in mind Scroll layout can hold only one type of item...

Once you do this, the whole layout is scroll able up and down or left and right as per your XML config.